# Splitting bezier/nurb paths into multiple strands?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I've been trying to add hair to my stylized character sculpt using the curve technique that many youtube tutorials teach, but I find myself quite stumped on something; If I want to have one strand of hair split into 2 smaller ends of hair, how would I do that?

I've kinda done this before by just duplicating the strand and moving the ends of the path slightly to achieve a similar effect, but this isn't ideal since it both doubles the polycount and doesn't really connect to the original strand organically (They're noclipping through each other)

[image: Example 1]

This is a scuffed diagram of what I'd like to do. Just be able to extrude at a node and it have it properly create a new strand instead of the mess it actually creates in blender

[image: Example 2]

Here's another diagram, from the artwork ([Artist](https://www.artstation.com/jin_k)) I'm basing the hair from. You can see how one 'thick' strand splits into 2 smaller curved strands

I imagine it might be possible by duplicating the strands, making them into a mesh, then sculpting them so that the seam and overlap are unnoticeable, however, this is pretty time consuming and forces me to retopolgize the hair; I'd be grateful to hear any techniques for doing this as easily as possible!

(There is a similar question involving cables, but I do believe it is a different enough issue to warrant a separate question. Sorry if it isn't)